# Custom java color creator?

Tags: java, swing, colors

There are only a few standard colors available in the API - [Java.Color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html). I want many more colors.
I want to create my custom colors using some GUI color maker, then get the code for that and save it as a custom color which can be used later.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Overkill, but have you tried [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org)?

Comment: @WChargin - Gimp ??? Photoshop, 3dstudio max, maya ? why ? :)

Comment: If your intent is to be able to choose a color *before* compiling (e.g., the developer picks it, not the user; I'm assuming this because of the answer you accepted) then GIMP may be useful because it also has other color- and image-related functions. Plus it's free :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this applet i use it when i want to find a particular colour code for a custom colour

http://www.javaview.de/vgp/tutor/color/PaColorDemo.html

just take note of the RGB values and build the custom colour using these

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [JColorChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html). It enable users to choose from a palette of colors. Read more at [How to Use Color Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html).

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://www.colorspire.com/rgb-color-wheel/ and select your color and in code create the color object with r, g, b values.